# Texture render does not work as verticies but works as classic old opengl code

Tags: opengl

The classic old codes work. Like `glBegin()` and `glEnd()`. But I want to make it more new style but not as much as version 3.3. But as vertices it does not work. I am working on MacBook Pro XCode.

c++ opengl glfw glew mac osx

It shows only colored surface. Not the picture.

```
 void DrawQuad( GLfloat PosX, GLfloat PosY, GLfloat PosZ, GLfloat edgeLength )
{

    GLfloat halfSideLength = edgeLength * 0.5f;
    GLfloat vertices[] =
    {
        PosX - halfSideLength, PosY - halfSideLength, PosZ, // bottom left
        PosX + halfSideLength, PosY - halfSideLength, PosZ, // bottom right
        PosX + halfSideLength, PosY + halfSideLength, PosZ, // top right
        PosX - halfSideLength, PosY + halfSideLength, PosZ // top left
    };
    GLfloat colour[] =
    {
        1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
        0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
        0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
        1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f
    };
    GLfloat map2D[] = {
        0.0f, 0.0f,
        1.0f, 0.0f,
        1.0f, 1.0f,
        0.0f, 1.0f
    };
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[1]);
    glPolygonMode( GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL );
    glEnableClientState( GL_VERTEX_ARRAY );
    glEnableClientState( GL_COLOR_ARRAY );
    glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY);
    glVertexPointer( 3, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertices );
    glTexCoordPointer( 2, GL_FLOAT, 0, map2D );
    glColorPointer( 3, GL_FLOAT, 0, colour );
    glDrawArrays( GL_QUADS, 0, 4 );
    glDisableClientState( GL_COLOR_ARRAY );
    glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState( GL_VERTEX_ARRAY );
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
}
```

But it works on the below:

```
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[1]);
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f(200.0f, 200.0f, -400.0f);
glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f(450.0f, 200.0f, -400.0f);
glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f(450.0f, 450.0f, -400.0f);
glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f(200.0f, 450.0f, -400.0f);
glEnd();
glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY);

Is not what you think you need. You want `GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY` there.

`GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY` is a texture target, like `GL_TEXTURE_2D` or `GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP`.

A `GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY` is a stack of 2D images, where filtering happens between the texels in a 2D layer, but not between layers, and the layer is indexed by a 0 based integer index. Typical use for a 2D array is flipbook animations.

Comment: Thank you for your kind help.